# Step in the derivation of the total idle time distribution of an M/G/1 queue

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

I'm trying to work my way through the proof of Thm. 1.11 in Kyprianou's *Introductory Lectures on Fluctuations of Levy Processes with Applications* but really struggle to understand the following step. The author shows that the process
$$
Y_t := e^{\theta X_t - \psi(\theta) t}
$$
is a martingale and then proceeds to distinguish between the cases of $\psi$ having either one or two roots. In case there is a single root, then this is $\theta^* = 0$ and he concludes that $\mathbb{P}(\overline{X}_\infty > x) = 1$ for every $x \geq 0 $, hence $\overline{X}_\infty = \infty$ a.s. So far so good. However, when there are two roots, choosing the largest one ($\theta^* > 0$) leads to the conclusion that $\overline{X}_\infty \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\theta^*)$. But it seems to me that the reasoning for the other root ($\theta^* = 0$) remains valid in this case as well, which would lead to a contradiction. The proof says to take $\theta^*$ as the largest root, but doesn't explain why this is necessary.

Edit: here's the snippet from the book:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain all the notation you're using? What are $X_t$, $\bar{X}_\infty$, $\psi(\theta)$ and so on?

Comment: @JamesMartin It's very difficult to do so because it requires a lot of background. $\psi(\theta)$ is the Laplace exponent of the input process, $\overline{X}_\infty$ is the limit of the running supremum at infinity, and $X_t$ is the input process (which is assumed to be spectrally negative Lévy).

Comment: Right. If $\theta^*>0$, and $Y_t=e^{\theta^* X_t}$ is a martingale started at $1$ with no positive jumps, then indeed by considering the martingale stopped at the first time it hits $y=e^{\theta^*x}>1$, you get that the probability that $X_t$ ever exceeds $x$ is at most $e^{-\theta^* x}$. If you also know for example that $\liminf_t X_t=-\infty$ a.s., so that $\liminf_t Y_t = 0$ a.s., then you can make this inequality into an equality and you get $\bar{X}_\infty\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\theta^*)$ as mentioned. What is the argument for the opposite conclusion that is bothering you?

Comment: @JamesMartin In the case where $\theta^* > 0$, the argument for $\theta^* = 0$ still holds ($Y_t = e^{\theta X_t - \psi(\theta) t}$ is a martingale for *any* $\theta \geq 0$), hence you would get a contradiction. But I think my misunderstanding is that the probability of exceeding $x$ is *at most* $e^{-\theta^*x}$, it was my understanding from the proof that it was *exactly* equal, because
$$
1 = e^{ \theta^* X_0} = \mathbb{E}[e^{\theta^* X_{\tau^+_x}} \chi_{ \{ \tau^+_x < \infty \} }] = e^{\theta^* x} \mathbb{P}(\tau^+_x < \infty)
$$

Comment: In the case $\theta=0$, your martingale $Y_t=e^{\theta X_t}$ is simply the constant process $Y_t\equiv 1$. You won't learn any interesting information about your process by considering the process $Y_t \equiv 1$.

Comment: The display equation you wrote is not true in general - you need some further information about the behaviour when it doesn't hit $x$. (For example, just consider the case where it a.s. converges to a limit in $(0,x)$. Then your RHS would be $0$, and something must have gone wrong.) A more general case might look something like \begin{equation}
1=e^{\theta^* X_0}=\mathbb{E}[e^{\theta^* X_{\tau_x^+}}\chi_{\tau_x^+<\infty} + e^{\theta^* X_\infty} \chi_{\tau_x^+=\infty}]
\end{equation}.

Comment: @JamesMartin I just transcribed this equation from the textbook (see edited question). Am I to understand the author is wrong here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146705/discussion-between-james-martin-and-othman-el-hammouchi).